# breeze EntityManager: how to attach plain javascript object

Tags: breeze

I have custom OData action that is called from my client.  The results from this action are a list of JSON objects which need to be merged back into the Breeze cache as entities.  How do I convert a JSON object into a Breeze entity and merge that entity back into the entityManager's cache?  Some code:

```
   $http.post('/odata/MyEntityType/MyCustomAction/', {
                    'someData': JSON.stringify(element1),
                    'SomeOtherData': JSON.stringify(element2)
                })
                .success(function (results) {
                    //results.value is an array of *MyEntityType* JSON objects.   `//Is there a way to convert these to breeze entities?`

                    });
```

Some things I have tried:

> manager.importEntities("MyEntityType", theJsonForAnEntity); //just stabbing in the dark here
>
> manager.createEntity("MyEntityType", theJsonForAnEntity); //error: A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed' does not allow you to attach an entity when an entity with the same key is already attached"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### createEntity won't work

Sorry, Jeremy, but that isn't going to work. Here's a test that shows why:

```
// Failing test
test("merge customer date into existing cached entity using `createEntity`", function () {
    var em = newEm();

    // Create an unchanged entity in cache as if it had been queried
    em.createEntity('Customer', {
        CustomerID: dummyCustID,
        CompanyName: 'Foo Co',
        ContactName: 'Ima Kiddin'
    }, UNCHGD);  // creates the entity in the Unchanged state

    // Try to merge some changes into that entity using createEntity.
    var changes = {
        CustomerID: dummyCustID,
        CompanyName: 'Bar Co',
    }
    var cust = em.createEntity('Customer', changes, 
                   UNCHGD, breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges);

    ok(cust.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged(), "cust should be 'Unchanged'");

    // using Knockout; it's simpler if using Angular
    equal(cust.CompanyName(), 'Bar Co', "Company name should be updated by merge'");
    equal(cust.ContactName(), 'Ima Kiddin', "Contact name should be unchanged after merge'");
});
```

The third assert fails because the `createEntity` method overwrites **every** property, not just the one data value of interest (`CompanyName` in this case). That means that `ContactName` is null.

### importEntities won't work either

For the same reason. When you import an entity, you import **the entire entity**, not just some portion of it. So that too would wipe out the `ContactName` in this example.

### Manual merge

I think if you want to *blend* the results with the entity in cache, you'll have to do that by hand. You'll have to iterate over the results and update the cached equivalents.

Imagine that the `changes` variable above is result of your POST. The following test does pass:

```
// Passing test
test("merge customer date into existing cached entity", function () {
    var em = newEm();

    // Create an unchanged entity in cache as if it had been queried
    em.createEntity('Customer', {
        CustomerID: dummyCustID,
        CompanyName: 'Foo Co',
        ContactName: 'Ima Kiddin'
    }, UNCHGD);  // creates the entity in the Unchanged state

    // Merge some changes into that entity
    // Imagine that `changes` came from your server as a result of your POST
    var changes = {
        CustomerID: dummyCustID,
        CompanyName: 'Bar Co',
    }

    // First find the customer in cache.
    // Here I'm assuming it will always be there; you should be careful
    var cust = em.getEntityByKey('Customer', changes.CustomerID);

    // using Knockout; it's a little simpler in Angular
    for (var p in changes) { cust[p](changes[p]); }

    cust.entityAspect.setUnchanged(); // cuz the previous updates changed the state to "Modified"

    ok(cust.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged(), "cust should be 'Unchanged'");
    equal(cust.CompanyName(), 'Bar Co', "Company name should be updated by merge'");
    equal(cust.ContactName(), 'Ima Kiddin', "Contact name should be unchanged after merge'");
});
```

### Feature Request

I can imagine a future in which Breeze could automate this for you with all of the appropriate error checks. If you think such a "JSON entity merge" feature would be a valuable enhancement to Breeze, please add that to [User Voice](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/). I would be quick to agree but we can't add features unless people want them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're onto something with the `manager.createEntity` approach.  Try specifying a merge strategy  (the default is "Disallowed" which is causing problems for your use case):

```
manager.createEntity("MyEntityType", thePocoEntityFromTheCustomODataAction, breeze.MergeStrategy.PreserveChanges);
```

Merge strategies:  http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MergeStrategy.html

createEntity:  http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_createEntity

Comment: by the way, nice name: "what evAR"